# Real time chat app using Polymer and node

Tags: node.js, session, websocket, polymer, primus

I have a node application using Polymer as front-end. The app runs behind an nginx reverse proxy, which deals with HTTPs etc using HTTP2. I am using cookie sessions with signed cookies.

I now need to add a "real time chat" to the app; I thought that in 2016 it would be easy... boy was I wrong.

My first port of call was Primus. But there are things I just don't quite get:

- What happens if the node server is restarted? Will all of the client need to reconnect?
- The clients can 'register' to specific event types (which are then supposed to receive via Primus/Websockets/etc.) So, each opened "tab" will need its own ID; if the server is restarted, and the client reconnect, can the server reuse the list of "subscriptions"? (this requires the client to have the same "id")

Is there a standard solution to all of this that I am not aware of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked recently on a chat project and I also used Polymer on the client side.

On the server side you could use [Feathers](http://feathersjs.com/) like I did. Basically Feathers is a minimalist wrapper over [Express](http://expressjs.com/) and uses Websockets and [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/) under the hood for the realtime communication. It works really well, you don't have to worry about creating connections and all that. They also have a client side JS library which you can easily wrap in a Polymer component.

> What happens if the node server is restarted? Will all of the client need to reconnect?

The answer is yes, they will reconnect automatically.

> The clients can 'register' to specific event types (which are then supposed to receive via Primus/Websockets/etc.) So, each opened "tab" will need its own ID ...

It is really up to you how you design your Feathers app. As I understand you want something like in Facebook, where you have these tabs with different people or multiple people.

For this, I used a Master-detail data structure:

Conversation (1) --- (n) Message

Example:

**Conversation**

```
{
  "doc_created_at": "2016-09-21T07:30:02.289Z",
  "doc_created_by": "299009a4-5423-4cdd-9e1a-59fca59404ae",
  "doc_id": "00f61c96-4bc6-4c46-a22d-de246314695c",
  "doc_patched_at": "2016-10-27T11:35:53.599Z",
  "doc_type": "conversation",
  "participants": [
    {
      "id": "635b05bc-ae23-4c5d-9ee5-87e7da2cac15",
      "name": "User 1"
    },
    {
      "id": "299009a4-5423-4cdd-9e1a-59fca59404ae",
      "name": "User 2"
    }
  ],
  "sender": {
    "id": "299009a4-5423-4cdd-9e1a-59fca59404ae",
    "name": "User 2"
  },
  "last_message": "How are you?"
}
```

**Message #1**

```
{
  "conversation_id": "00f61c96-4bc6-4c46-a22d-de246314695c",
  "doc_created_at": "2016-09-23T06:10:28.727Z",
  "doc_created_by": "299009a4-5423-4cdd-9e1a-59fca59404ae",
  "doc_id": "00e5b904-c9fa-46f1-b108-9fc9a15d11fc",
  "doc_type": "message",
  "participants": [
    {
      "id": "635b05bc-ae23-4c5d-9ee5-87e7da2cac15",
      "name": "User 1"
    },
    {
      "id": "299009a4-5423-4cdd-9e1a-59fca59404ae",
      "name": "User 2"
    }
  ],
  "sender": {
    "id": "299009a4-5423-4cdd-9e1a-59fca59404ae",
    "name": "User 2"
  },
  "message": "Hi"
}
```

**Message #2**

```
{
  "conversation_id": "00f61c96-4bc6-4c46-a22d-de246314695c",
  "doc_created_at": "2016-09-21T07:32:08.312Z",
  "doc_created_by": "299009a4-5423-4cdd-9e1a-59fca59404ae",
  "doc_id": "2a6c2f91-04a8-4447-a0a6-4b229d523afc",
  "doc_type": "message",
  "participants": [
    {
      "id": "635b05bc-ae23-4c5d-9ee5-87e7da2cac15",
      "name": "User 1"
    },
    {
      "id": "299009a4-5423-4cdd-9e1a-59fca59404ae",
      "name": "User 2"
    }
  ],
  "sender": {
    "id": "299009a4-5423-4cdd-9e1a-59fca59404ae",
    "name": "User 2"
  },
  "message": "How are you?"
}
```

I stored these information in a database ([Couchbase](http://www.couchbase.com/)).

Comment: Please let me know, if you need more details.

Comment: Accepting this answer as it's the only sane answer possible. But, I ended up writing [my own server code](https://github.com/mercmobily/hotplate/blob/master/core_modules/hotCoreComet/lib/hotCoreComet.js) and [my own client library](https://github.com/mercmobily/hotplate/blob/master/core_modules/hotCoreComet/lib/comet-client.js) for this, and wrapped the client library with three polymer widgets...